# Why when I install firebase in my projects do my react-native commands get deleted?

Tags: android, mobile, react-native

Everything in my prooject works fine and I do not get any errors with android studio. I get an output and so on. As soon I install firebase, I do get some errors, but at face value it looks like the installation went well. At most I get the below. Are these significant issues?

```
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\uuid.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\uuid
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\uuid as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\uuid
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\jsesc.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\jsesc
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\jsesc as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\jsesc
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\esparse.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\esvalidate.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\esparse as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\.bin\esvalidate as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\ferre\react\auth\node_modules\esprima
```

I then cannot use `react-native run-android` anymore and says the command is `unrecognized`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

1) I was adding firebase with `npm install` rather than `yarn add`. Apparently this is a common problem. However, it may not be common that the version of firebase you install can cause problems. The version that worked for me was `firebase@5.0.3`

2) Another problem was that as a result of this installation, certain files in `node_modules` were being shaken up. Solved this by `brute force copying and pasting from a fresh react-native project`.

3) Lastly, one of my filepaths in my project was messed up.

Sorry for a rather insignificant question, but I hope this answer gives significant results to anyone who needs it.